# Adding a selection box into an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have a WPF ItemsControl with a Canvas ItemPanel. Drawing from an internal source, it displays lots of automatically generated Rectangles.

As of now, it looks like this:

```
<Window    
// .. NameSpaces
  >
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="binTemplate">
      <Rectangle x:Name="Rect" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                 Canvas.Left="10" StrokeThickness="0">
        // .. Databinding Height, Width, etc
      </Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" LastChildFill="True">
      <ItemsControl
          ItemsSource="{Binding Bins}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource binTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp">
              <Rectangle x:Name="Selection" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Visibility="Hidden" />
            </Canvas>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I now try to implement a selection box, too.. well.. select my Rectangles. =)
I tried just adding the box into the ItemsControl PanelTemplate, and controlling it with the Canvas mouse events, but it appears I am not allowed to do so. The error message is "Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel."

What is the preferred way to implement such behavior? I thought about overlaying another canvas (using negative Margin) and drawing the selection box in there, but that seems like a bad hack.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding the selection box to the `Canvas`, you should add it as an [`Adorner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adorner.aspx) over the `Canvas`. To retrieve the `AdornerLayer` for the `Canvas`, you can use the [`AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer.getadornerlayer.aspx) method, or wrap the `Canvas` in an [`AdornerDecorator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerdecorator.aspx) and use its `AdornerLayer` property.

Comment: Wrapping the canvas in an `AdornerDecorator` does not work, since ItemPanelTemplate only accepts Panels, but I think I can get this working in the code behind. Thanks!